# Electron render process cannot find 'electron-cookies' modules

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a website that I am trying to get running as a desktop app using electron. Everything is working except cookies. I use passport to identify users when they return to the website. I am trying to use the electron-cookies module.

I have installed the module using npm install --save electron-cookies. The module files exist in the node_modules folder, and the module is listed as a dependency in package.json. I understand that the module needs to be included in the render process and not the main process. I could be misunderstanding what is meant by the render process. I think it means the code running in the front-end, which would include scripts contained inside the html document.

In the html file served by my website, just before I include all the javascript files I have the following code:

```
<script>
if(module) {
    require('electron-cookies');
}
</script>
```

I check for the existence of module so the code will run in electron, but not in a web browser.

The electron debug tools give the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'electron-cookies'
```

I should also note that I am loading the webpage in electron using loadURL. Would that effect loading node modules in the project?

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:8080`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [native Electron Cookies interface](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#class-cookies). The electron-cookies third party lib you're trying to load seems a little out of date and is probably no longer working with current versions of Electron.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did eventually realize this eventually. Also wanted to note for anyone else coming in the future that cookies get wiped every time you start electron from the command-line. If you build the app into an executable and launch it the cookies are saved between application uses.